# MU and the integral Hodge Conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, hodge-theory

Totaro proved that the cycle class map for an algebraic variety factors through complex cobordism. In other words, we have a factorization

$$CH^i(X) \rightarrow MU^{2i}(X) \rightarrow H^{2i}(X; \mathbb{Z}).$$

This is supposed to given a conceptual explanation for the Atiyah-Hirzebruch topological obstructions to the integral Hodge conjecture. More precisely, the claim is that any odd degree cohomology operation on integral cohomology should lift to $MU$ (where it has to be 0), and therefore kill the cycle class of an algebraic variety. (See top of 2nd page of [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870811000776/1-s2.0-S0001870811000776-main.pdf?_tid=5e7f4e20-ac6a-11e6-b2b3-00000aacb360&acdnat=1479348533_6c5f33971cb0459952ca84987e586eeb).)

The point I don't understand is: why must a cohomology operation on $H\mathbb{Z}$ lift to $MU$?

Comment: I'd perhaps refer you to Landweber's papers On the Complex Bordism of Eilenberg-Mac Lane Spaces and Connective Coverings of BU" and "Steenrod Representability of Stable Homotopy" in which he computes the image of the Thom map $MU_*(K(\mathbb{Z},q))\rightarrow H^*(K(\mathbb{Z},q);\mathbb{Z})$. If i recall, the Thom map is surjective in many situations.